# External style stopped loading in angular 2 component after moving file

Tags: angular

I have been following the tutorial "Tour of Heroes" on angular.com, and after completing that, I thought I would rework the folder to be more in line with how I would set things up in a real environment.

The chief concern I had was how polluted the source folder was with compiled .js files, so I changed tsconfig to output to a dist folder.

```
{
  "compilerOptions":
  {
...
    "outDir": "./dist"
  }
}
```

I got the js to load after modifying systemjs config, but my templates were not loading because they did not get copied to tsc's output folder.

I then moved these files into a new folder "view" and changed the code accordingly. However, only the html component loaded, so the demo lost all it's style.

This is how the dashboard component is defined;

```
@Component(
  {
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'my-dashboard',
    templateUrl: '/view/dashboard.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ '/view/dashboard.component.css' ]
  }
)
```

Both the css and html file exists in the /view/ folder under my project root, but only the html part is getting loaded.
There are no http requests being made for the css file.

Comment: Have you tried a *relative path* to the template and stylesheet?

Comment: absolute path works for the template, so I would expect it to also work for the stylesheet. No errors in the console, nor any 404 requests, so I find it hard to believe that is relevant, but I shall give it a try none the less.

Comment: Using a relative path for the css does makes it load. Some kind of bug?